# Attribute "data-content-id" inside of a div

Tags: html

I've a div `class="contentMiddle">`. I need to give that container a "data content id".

Can I do it like this?

```
<div class="contentMiddle" data-contentid="1">CONTENT</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure!

There is no reason that you can't have a class and an id on an element. You just can't have more than one id. That's a bit of a rule of thumb when it comes to programming.

Check out http://html5doctor.com/html5-custom-data-attributes/ for more.

Please post a link to example code if you need SO users to dig deeper.